# How to compress and resize canvas image with pure javascript and HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to resize and rotate a camera picture in the client side - without any special libraries, I actually managed to do most of the work only that I get an offset of 320 pixels when rotating the image. I'm not sure where this offset is coming from and how I could fix this. Any clues? Here is my code:

```
    function processFile(dataURL, fileType) 
    {
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = dataURL;

    image.onload = function () 
        {
        var width = image.width;
        var height = image.height;
        canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

        var compressionQuality = "10"; // this is % i.e. the number should run between 1 to 100, 100 is the highest quality (less compression), 1 is the highest compression (lowest quality)
        var mime_type;
         if(fileType==="png"){
            mime_type = "image/png";
         } else if(fileType==="webp") {
            mime_type = "image/webp";
         } else {
            mime_type = "image/jpeg";
         }
        var cvs = document.createElement('canvas');     

        if (window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth)
            { //landscape picture - rotate by 90 degrees
            var newWidth = height;
            var newHeight = width;
            cvs.width = newWidth;
            cvs.height = newHeight;
            var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");
            rotateDegrees=-90;
            ctx.clearRect(0,0,width,height);
            ctx.translate(newWidth/2,newHeight/2);
            ctx.rotate(rotateDegrees*Math.PI/180);
            ctx.drawImage(image,-newWidth/2-320,-newHeight/2+320); // <<<--- here I offset by 320px
            }
        else
            {
            cvs.width = width;
            cvs.height = height;
            var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");
            ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
            }
         dataURL = cvs.toDataURL(mime_type, compressionQuality/100);            

        sendFile(dataURL);

        };
```

When I move the image by 320px I managed to resolve this by I think that the 320px are dependent on the image size (in that case it is 1900px width)
[image: offseted image]

I appreciate any help or ideas! thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you translate to the center of the canvas to rotate, then immediately try to draw. Your ctx origin in still in the center of the canvas, so you draw with offset.

You need to translate to the new origin before drawing.